# SQLite3 Shell: How to get database filename inside .sql file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlite

I'm writing a .bat file that calls sqlite3 shell (opens existing database file) and passes an .sql file with commands into it. 
It looks like following in .bat file:

```
sqlite3 %1 < "%~0\..\xtra.sql"
```

, where %1 is path to database file.

The problem is - **in .sql script I need to use filename of database;** but I can't find any information which command use to get it.
Alternatively,if there is a way to pass parameters into sqlite3 shell (like into windows cmd), I could use it too.

Answer (score 2):

The `pragma database_list;` command will return the list of currently attached databases. This information can be retrieved as a table-valued function (from version 3.16.0, documented [here](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)).

As you need your default database file, then if you are using an updated `sqlite` shell version, you can use

```
select file from pragma_database_list where name='main';
```